# Why does my bar chart's values don't start in a horizontal line?

Tags: reporting-services

I tried to play with the minimum values of my axis because I had a problem with the pagination of my chart.

I found a solution, but now I have an other problem.

My chart is actually like this :

[image]

As you can see, the values are not on the horizontal line and I can't see the `0`.

So what I want is something like this :

[image]

Here is my Vertical Properties :

[image]

The expression is :

```
=MAX(SUM(Fields!Montant_Historique.Value, "Chart10_CategoryGroup"))*-2
```

And my dataset :

3 values :

1. Amount_QTY
2. Revenues
3. Amount_order

And the Category Groups is "period".

Comment: I would add a Maximum formula that matches the Min (sand the negative sign - `=MAX(SUM(Fields!Montant_Historique.Value, "Chart10_CategoryGroup")) * 2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is because your vertical axis range does not start and end on values that, once divided into major bands, will give a 0.

You can correct this by doing two things.

1. Make sure you min and max axis values are rounded to the nearest band size that you want
2. Setting the Interval size to the band size that you want.

In this example I've fixed the interval at 2000 and made sure the min axis value is a multiple of 2000.

This is before the change...

[image]

I then set the Interval to 2000 and the Min value to

```
=CINT((MAX(SUM(Fields!myValue.Value, "Chart1_CategoryGroup"))*-2) / 2000) * 2000
```

[image]

This is the result after the changes

[image]

You might need to add expressions to get the correct interval size (where I have hardcoded 2000) depending on your needs and then replace all 3 instances of "2000" with this expression.

**Note:** I set max axis value to 6000 manually as I didn't have any data in the positive range, so you may have to do a similar method with the max axis value too.

Comment: very usefull thank you!